# How to span \left\{ and \right\} over multiple alignat columns?

Tags: delimiters, alignat

I would like to specify two very similar equations underneath each other, and align them at some points using the `alignat` environment. My code so far:

```
\begin{alignat}{3} 
D_s &= \{ (s_1, s_2)\quad & \forall\ &s_1, s_2\neq s_1 \quad && 
\begin{array}{|l}
 G_{s_1} \cap G_{s_2} \neq \{\} \\
 s_1 \notin \mathbb{D}(s_2) \wedge s_2 \notin \mathbb{D}(s_1)
 \end{array} \}\\
D_p &= \{ (p_1, p_2) & \forall\ &p_1, p_2\neq p_1 && 
\begin{array}{|l}
 G_{p_1} \cap G_{p_2} \neq \{\} \\
 p_1 \notin \mathbb{D}(p_2) \wedge p_2 \notin \mathbb{D}(p_1)
 \end{array}\}
\end{alignat}
```

gives me the following equations:

[image]

The alignment works perfectly. I would just like to increase the size of the outer braces, to make it look more like:

[image]

However, it seems that `\left\{` and `\right\}` cannot span over multiple `alignat` columns.. How to change the above code to get the alignment of the first picture with the big braces from the second one?

Comment: Try with `\left\{...\right.` and `\left.\right\}` shall I post a `MWE`?

Answer (score 2):

A solution with the  `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command from `mathtools` and the `eqparbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{eqparbox} 
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\set}[1]\{\}{\setargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargs}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}
{\setargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setargsaux}{mm}
{\IfNoValueTF{#2}{#1}{\nonscript\,#1\nonscript\;\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:\allowbreak #2\nonscript\,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  D_s &= \set[\bigg]{\eqmathbox{(s_1, s_2)\quad \forall s_1, s_2\neq s_1};
\begin{aligned}
  &G_{s_1} \cap G_{s_2} \neq \{\} \\
  &s_1 \notin \mathbb{D}(s_2) \wedge s_2 \notin \mathbb{D}(s_1)
\end{aligned}}
\\[1.5ex]
D_p &= \set*{\eqmathbox{(p_1, p_2) \forall p_1, p_2\neq p_1} ;
    \begin{aligned}
      & G_{p_1} \cap G_{p_2} \neq \{\} \\
      & p_1 \notin \mathbb{D}(p_2) \wedge p_2 \notin \mathbb{D}(p_1)
    \end{aligned}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. The fences produced by `\set*` seem needlessy tall, though; `\set[\bigg]` might be preferable.

Comment: @Mico: you're probably right, albeit one may wonder whether it's an optical effect, due to the single-lined left side  of the sets. I posted the version with [\bigg]  for the first equation, so anyone interested in this solution may compare. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would employ a plain `align` environment and use `\biggl\lbrace`, `\biggm\vert`, and `\biggr\rbrace` to create the "fence" symbols. Observe that `\biggm\vert` automatically inserts a bit of whitespace -- appropriate for a relational operator -- on both sides of the vertical bar.

You could replace the `array` environment with an `aligned` environment if you want the contents to be typeset in `\displaystyle` rather than in `\textstyle` math. For the case at hand, it won't make a difference, though.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
D_s &= \biggl\lbrace 
       (s_1, s_2)\quad \forall\ s_1, s_2\neq s_1 \,
       \biggm\vert
       \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
          G_{s_1} \cap G_{s_2} \neq \emptyset \\
          s_1 \notin \mathbb{D}(s_2) \wedge s_2 \notin \mathbb{D}(s_1)
       \end{array} 
       \biggr\rbrace \\[1ex]
D_p &= \biggl\lbrace 
       (p_1, p_2) \quad\forall\ p_1, p_2\neq p_1 
       \biggm\vert
       \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
          G_{p_1} \cap G_{p_2} \neq \emptyset \\
          p_1 \notin \mathbb{D}(p_2) \wedge p_2 \notin \mathbb{D}(p_1)
       \end{array}
       \biggr\rbrace
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment: Since the suggested solution uses `\biggl`, `\biggm`, and `\biggr` rather than `\left`, `\middle`, and `\right` to resize the fence symbols, it is indeed possible to combine the approach with an `alignat` environment, along the following lines (no screenshot posted since the outcome looks very similar to the one above):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{4}
D_s &= \biggl\lbrace (s_1, s_2)\quad 
    &&\forall\ s_1, s_2\neq s_1 
    &&\biggm\vert
      \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
          G_{s_1} \cap G_{s_2} \neq \emptyset \\
          s_1 \notin \mathbb{D}(s_2) \wedge s_2 \notin \mathbb{D}(s_1)
      \end{array} 
    &&\biggr\rbrace \\[1ex]
D_p &= \biggl\lbrace (p_1, p_2)  
    &&\forall\ p_1, p_2\neq p_1 
    &&\biggm\vert
      \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
          G_{p_1} \cap G_{p_2} \neq \emptyset \\
          p_1 \notin \mathbb{D}(p_2) \wedge p_2 \notin \mathbb{D}(p_1)
      \end{array}
    &&\biggr\rbrace
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I copied the code, but the `\vert` were shifted horizontally (unlike your picture). So I ended up with the second picture from my original answer. However, because you avoided using `\left` and `\right`, I was able to get the correct result by using `alignat` after all. The code looks a bit messy, but the result is exactly how I like it, many thanks!

Comment: @TorbenB - I've gone ahead and posted an addendum to the address, to show how I would implement the suggested solution via an `alignat{4}` environment. Presumably, it's similar to what you've come up with.